# Disable auto rotation for video entering full screen mode in Chrome Android

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, screen-rotation, android-fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

Is there a way to disable auto rotation for video entering full screen mode in Chrome Android?

I would like to prevent video rendering to a landscape mode when user clicks on full screen.